# Remove Joomla module border

Tags: joomla, module

My website is http://picofdel.org/services/educators-professionals/professional-development.html
I have added a custom HTML module at position content-top-b for skip navigation link.
The code is

```
<div id="main" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; border: none;">&nbsp;</div>
```

But, a thin border is appearing on the page around the module. Please tell me how to remove the border.

Comment: specific your question. Make a screenshot for the target element!

Comment: The module is appearing with a thin border just above "Professional Development" heading on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these stylesheet to your head or body. Otherwise you can add this simple line to your css-file (without script tag).

```
 <style type="text/css">
      .module-outline-2 { border: none !important; }
 </style>
```

the border will be defined on following file:
http://picofdel.org/templates/ca_cloudbase2_j25/css/template.css on **Line 316**:

```
#rt-top .module-outline-2, 
#rt-content-top .module-outline-2, 
#rt-content-bottom .module-outline-2,
#rt-bottom .module-outline-2{
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
```